# Vonage server sdk for node js

Tags: node.js, vonage

I was trying to use the **@vonage/server-sdk** package for sending sms using a node js server integrated with docker. So when trying to run the docker-compose up command for the server,
I am getting the following error for the voange sdk package.

"node_modules/@vonage/voice/dist/classes/NCCO/Conversation.d.ts(15,46): error TS2694: Namespace '"/app/node_modules/@vonage/voice/dist/types"' has no exported member '**ConversationAction**'."

Similar error also appears for a member **StreamAction**.

Tried an alternative with the **@vonage/messages package**. I am able to send the request , but even after setting the auth config using the API key and Secret, the request doesn't seem to append those as authorization headers but seems to being appended to the request body and hence getting 401(Unauthorized) error.

It would be much appreciated, if i could get a solution for this.